# How to read a binary file with fread()

Tags: c, text, io, binary

I'm writing a function that has to traverse through a binary file and write it to a text file. Each line of the binary file contains
l1 firstname l2 lastname ID GPA
ex) Mary Joeseph 1234 4.0

Where l1 and l2 are the lengths of first and last name, respectively, ID is an unsigned int, and GPA is a float (each 4 bytes).
How can I correctly implement a loop to traverse the binary file until it reaches EOF? Currently, the resulting text file is gibberish for the most part, how can I fix it? Any help is appreciated.

```
int binaryToText() //add parameters
{

unsigned char firstName[255];
unsigned char lastName[255];
unsigned int id;
float gpa;
char nLine[]= "\n";
char space[]= " ";


FILE * binfile = fopen("b2.bin", "r"); //Open and read binary file binfile
FILE * textfile = fopen("b2totxt.txt", "w");//Open and write to text file



if(NULL == binfile) //alerts and exits if binfile is not found
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file\n");
    fflush(stderr);
    exit(1);
}


fread(&firstName, sizeof(firstName), 1, binfile);
fread(&lastName, sizeof(lastName), 1, binfile);
fread(&id, sizeof(id), 1, binfile);
fread(&gpa, sizeof(gpa), 1, binfile);

printf("%s %s %u %f", firstName, lastName, id, gpa); //test(doesnt come out right)

fprintf(textfile, "%s %s %u %1.1f\n", firstName, lastName, id, gpa);//also flawed





fclose(textfile);
fclose(binfile); //close bin file
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Please do atleast a google search before asking such questions.

Comment: Can you post an actual line? If it's a binary file, presumably l1, l2, ID, and GPA are exactly 4 bytes, not something like 3 bytes of ASCII "4.0". Is there a blank between each field and a CR or LF or CRLF at the end of each line?

Comment: If you are using a file written with `fwrite(firstName, strlen(firstName), 1, binfile);
fwrite(lastName, strlen(lastName), 1, binfile);` of your previous post, this code will have trouble knowing where one name ended and the other began.  Need to re-plan the output from that file.  I predict yet a 3rd post from @OP this week-end.

Comment: As an example, a binary file might have a record that looks like "\0\0\0\x04Mary\0\0\0\x06Joseph\0\0\x04\xd2\x40\x80\0\0". It might even have fixed-sized areas for the first and last name.

Comment: How could i open the binary file and copy a line? In notepad it is a bunch of gibberish and symbols. Sorry I'm quite a novice.

Comment: Notepad can't really handle non-text files. Try a [hex editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_editor).

Answer (score 4):

You want to read binary data, however, your file is open for *reading text* (`"r"`) instead of *reading binary* (`"rb"`). Hence, `fread()` is possibly translating `"\r\n"` to `"\n"`, which could cause issues when the underlying representation of a particular `unsigned int` or `float` value contains `"\r\n"` sequences.

Change this:

```
FILE * binfile = fopen("b2.bin", "r");
```

To this:

```
FILE * binfile = fopen("b2.bin", "rb");
```

In `"rb"`, the `b` stands for binary mode.

---

However, I don't think this is your main problem, as your *binary file* doesn't actually contain *binary representations* of data; it contains *human-readable representations* (based on the example you gave). You should be using `fscanf`, *not `fread`* to read that data.

Change this:

```
fread(&firstName, sizeof(firstName), 1, binfile);
fread(&lastName, sizeof(lastName), 1, binfile);
fread(&id, sizeof(id), 1, binfile);
fread(&gpa, sizeof(gpa), 1, binfile);
```

To this:

```
int n = fscanf(binfile, "%s %s %u %f", firstName, lastName, &id, &gpa);
```

Comment: You are correct about the "rb", I missed that myself. However, the data is in binary, the example I gave is technically what it should translate to in the text file, so I think fread() is still the function I should use. Any help with the loop? I'm lost on that part. Thank you

Comment: What have you tried? You should ask a question about that, noting any misbehaviour or error messages, and asking what you're confused about...

Answer (score 0):

`FILE * binfile = fopen("b2.bin", "r");`

This should be

`FILE * binfile = fopen("b2.bin", "rb");`
To open any binary files.